# Using bash system calls in C to write C that makes bash system calls

Tags: c, bash, escaping, echo, system-calls

I'm playing around with a tiny app (in C) that, when run, creates a directory tree which it populates with files.  It does this by using a series of lines of the form

`system("echo \"lump = \" >> ./newdirectory/newfile.c");`

This is working fine, except for when I try to have it write a line of C into the new file which itself contains a `system("echo");` call.

Specifically,

`system("echo \"system(\"echo hello world\");\" >> ./newdirectory/newfile.c");`

gets written as

`system(echo hello world);`

Comment: It is possible to do what you're trying to do, but you will be happier in the long run if you learn how to create files directly from C rather than by messing around with `system`.  Alternatively, you could write a regular old shell script instead of dressing it up in a C costume.

Comment: Agreed; this is more of an exercise than an actual project.  I suppose my real curiosity is just what I'm doing wrong with the escape characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want the escape characters to appear as-is, you need to escape them too. Yes, you can escape escape characters. Something like:

```
"\\\""
```

This results in outputting a `\` followed by an `"`.

Comment: system("echo \"system(\\\"echo hello world\\\");\" >> ./newdirectory/newfile.c");

Comment: @elempenguin Thanks. Don't forget to actually "Accept" the answer that solves your question.

Comment: A popup box tells me that I can accept your answer in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

It is crazy play.
But I think, right way of this crazyness is writing C function to escape string.

Internal string must be double escaped.

```
system("echo \"system(\\\"echo hello world\\\");\" >> ./newdirectory/newfile.c");
```

Othervise first C unescape literal string and shell get

```
echo "system("echo hello world");" >> ./newdirectory/newfile.c
```

It wrong quotes in echo not escaped.